# Como conseguir um retorno de um Array<String> em uma chamada GET com o task.resume()?

Tags: array, swift, rest, get

Boa tarde, pessoal. Estou com dificuldade em carregar o conteúdo de um PickerView no meu app, pois para isso ele precisa buscar as informações em uma chamada `GET`, a chamada funciona e eu consigo montar o `array` com o conteúdo que preciso, mas não consigo fazer com que a função que constrói o `array` o retorne para que eu carregue no PickerView. Construo um `array` de categorias e, a partir dele, extraio somente a informação "descrição" de cada categoria que existe no `array`, para carregar no PickerView. Segue abaixo a parte do meu código que estou com problemas:

```
var categoriaArray = Array<Categoria>()

for obj:AnyObject in post {
    let dict = obj as! NSDictionary
    let categoria = Categoria()

    categoria.descricao = dict["descricao"] as! String
    categoria.id = dict["id"] as! Int
    categoria.valorCasadinha = dict["valorCasadinha"] as! Double
    categoria.valorTerceira = dict["valorTerceira"] as! Double

    categoriaArray.append(categoria)
}

var descricoes = Array<String>()

for categoria in categoriaArray{
    descricoes.append(categoria.descricao)
}

print("Descrições: \(descricoes)")
print("Quantidade de Categorias: \(categoriaArray.count)")

})
task.resume()
```

Consigo imprimir o conteúdo do `array` que preciso (descricoes), mas preciso que ele seja retornado na função que o constrói, ou seja, preciso de um `return descricoes` após o `task.resume()`. Espero que possam me ajudar. Desde já obrigada.

Comment: Tem como colocar mais código? De forma geral se seu array tem os valores que você espera então, tecnicamente, tudo que você precisaria era dar `reload` no picker e fazer com que ele pegue os novos valores do array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é passando um callback pra sua função:

```
class func getDescricoes(completionHandler: (result: Array<String>) -> ()) {
    ...
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {
        data, response, error in
        ...
        for categoria in categoriaArray{
            descricoes.append(categoria.descricao)
        }

        completionHandler(result: descricoes)
    }
    ...
    task.resume()
}
```

para chamar esse método:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    Ingressos.getDescricoes {
        result in
        println("Descrições: \(result)")     
    }
}
```

*ps.: recomendo dar uma olhada no framework [Alamofire](https://github.com/alamofire/alamofire), ele é simples e fácil de trabalhar a parte de conexão em aplicativos.*

Answer (score 0):

Obrigada, iTSagnar.

Eu fiz desse jeito e deu certo. Com o Alamofire eu tentei também, mas comigo ele não foi muito simples :/ Mas consegui meu retorno. Obrigada :D

Comment: Eu criei um projeto de exemplo de [como utilizar o Alamofire para API's REST](https://github.com/iTSangarDEV/Routimofire). Eu uso essa base que criei para meus projetos junto com o [ObjectMapper para modelagem de objetos](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper). Talvez olhando um exemplo você consiga entender melhor ;)